# How to get unique visists per day using GAPI and Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I have a very simple custom report in Google Analytics that lists Date, Visits, Unique Visitors and Pageviews for a certain month.

I am trying to duplicate this very simple report using GAPI, but I cannot find a simple way to add Unique Visitors to my table.

See my code below. How can I modify this code to show Unique Visitors?

```
$profile_id = "xxxxxxxx";
$report_id = "xxxxxxxx";
$dimensions = array('date');
$metrics = array('pageviews','visits');
$sort_metric = array('date'); 
$filter = null;
$start_date = '2013-02-01';
$end_date = '2013-02-28';
$start_index = 1;
$max_results = 10000;

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Date</th>';
echo '<th>Visits</th>';
echo '<th>Unique Visitors</th>';
echo '<th>Page Views</th>';      
echo '</tr>';   

$ga = new gapi('xx@xxxxxxxxx.com','xxxxxxxx'); 

$ga->requestReportData($profile_id, $dimensions, $metrics, $sort_metric, $filter, $start_date, $end_date, $start_index, $max_results); 

foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
    echo '<td>' . $result->getDate() . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->getVisits() . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . '?' . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $result->getPageviews() . '</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';  
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

The metric is called visitors and no visitor and you have to change the dimension to `userDefinedValue`

```
$profile_id = "xxxxxxxx";
$report_id = "xxxxxxxx";
$dimensions = array('userDefinedValue');
$metrics = array('pageviews','visits','visitors');
$sort_metric = array('date'); 
$filter = null;
$start_date = '2013-02-01';
$end_date = '2013-02-28';
$start_index = 1;
$max_results = 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

The metric is called "visitor".  Try adding it to your report.

Answer (score 0):

```
$profile_id = "xxxxxxxx";
$report_id = "xxxxxxxx";
$dimensions = array('date');
$metrics = array('pageviews','visits','visitors');
$sort_metric = array('date'); 
$filter = null;
$start_date = '2013-02-01';
$end_date = '2013-02-28';
$start_index = 1;
$max_results = 10000;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this may answer the question, providing more information about how this answers the question would make this a much better answer.